# Edge extension can not get upload file name in onchange event?

Tags: javascript, microsoft-edge-extension

In Edge extension I want to get all upload file name.Here is my code:

```
document.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    const element = event.srcElement;
    const elementName = element.localName;
    if (elementName === 'input') {
        if (element.getAttribute('type') === 'file') {
            element.onchange = function (e) {
                console.log(e.target.value);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

But, this console.log is :

```
{"notifyType":"consoleItemLog","message":{"message":"","styles":"","hasFormatString":true,"targetId":"uid36","fileUrl":"js/contentscript.js","lineNumber":49,"columnNumber":17}}
```

I do not know how to get upload file name?
And when I console.log(e), the onchange is permission denied.

[image]

thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I can see that you want to use OnChange Event, But I don't understand where you want to use this event.
It is better that you use the click event of button to get list of uploaded file.
Below is a sample code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to create a File Upload Button.</p>
<input type="file" id="fileElementId" name="files[]" multiple/>
<button onclick="fun2()">Try it</button>

<script>

function fun2()
{
var inp = document.getElementById('fileElementId');
for (var i = 0; i < inp.files.length; ++i) {
  var name = inp.files.item(i).name;
  //alert("here is a file name: " + name);
  console.log("here is a file name: " + name);
}
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Output:
[Click here to see the output:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XDdKf.gif)

Regards

Deepak

Comment: Thanks for your reply！It works well. But my question is in Microsoft Edge Browser extension(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/extensions/api-support).I want to write a Edge extension to get any upload file name.My code works well in chrome-extension. But not well in Edge browser extension. anyway, thank you very much.